# Carrier Waves, modulation over RF vs on wire

Tags: modulation, digital-modulation, sdr

I’m reading about carrier waves and signal modulation.  It appears signaling has differences over RF vs wire. RF requires accelerating charges to induce a voltage change at the receiver. Straight wire only requires moving charges through the conductor.

From this, it seems I could generate a square wave for straight wire, but over RF it would just be seen as voltage spikes at the rise and fall at the receiver. As such the square wave requires modulation of higher frequency carrier wave. **Is this true?**

I note that FM carrier is a certain frequency.  The modulated FM signal changes frequency with time.  **Is modulated FM signal and the carrier multiplied before transmission?**

Comment: Forget about "accelerated charges". That's not what happens, otherwise you could not have radio waves in vacuum (nor light, which are the same at even higher frequencies). I don't know where you have that from, but either it predates 1880’s physics, or is taken out of context. The fact that you can see the sun and receive satellite TV proves accelerated charges have nothing to do with it :)

Comment: Re accelerated charges: “ An accelerating charged particle produces an electromagnetic (EM) wave.” This must be wrong.  http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m6/production_of_em_waves.html

Comment: No it is not. That is **one** way of producing an electromagnetic wave. But not the only way. And not what happens in an antenna.

Comment: Again, read closely. One way, not the only way. You do not require (as you claim in your question) an accelerated charged particle. A harmonically time-changing electrical or magnetic field works just as well. You get that through an electrical current for example. And don't start with electrons - these are delocalized, i.e. especially *not* particles, in something like a metal conductor such as an antenna.

Comment: I literally answered that in my last comment. You might want to review a bit of physical basics - static electrical fields, potential, static magnetic fields and currents, before learning about the linked differential equations that explain em waves: Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Wait, accelerating charges (in the sun for instance) like the electron can produce a wave which can travel in a vacuum so there’s no problem there.  How do you create this harmonic oscillating EM field without charged particles involved? Also, you say antennas have no accelerating charges like electrons when rising voltage is applied? Something else happens. What?

Comment: At RF frequencies, signals moving down a wire at not carried by the motion of electrons down the wire, rather they move as waves in the dielectric around the wire.  It is tempting to think that RF signals move the same as DC does down wires, but this is not the case.

Comment: @Nick I believe the distinction the others are trying to make is the difference between a charged particle moving down a particle accelerator and producing electromagnetic waves versus the changing current in a wire producing electromagnetic waves. The current in a wire technically isn't electrons cleanly flowing down the wire like water in a pipe. The net movement of electrons along the length the wire is around walking speed but obviously the electrical signal itself which carries the information and energy moves down the wire at significant fractions of the speed of light.

Comment: Also consider that EM waves are generated from things that cause electrons to drop energy levels and emit photons. So just getting something really hot or otherwise energetic is enough. Though we obviously don't make radio transmissions like this (we do make light like that though).

Comment: @MarcusMüller, How is the (AC) electric current in the wire not an example of accelerating charges? There is a confusion here about whether the question is about how the wave is produced vs how it propagates (and at a deeper level they are the same thing), but it's wrong to say that an antenna doesn't involve accelerating charges.

Comment: (and yes, for a loop antenna the mechanism is different, but there certainly are antennas that generate an EM wave by accelerating charges)

Comment: @ThePhoton heh, the person with the handle that's the particle form of a wave/particle entity arguing that current is accelerated charges, does in fact, have something soothing. But I digress: if the current in an antenna was accelerated charges, the speed at which they change direction would be limited not only by Maxwell, but also by inertia! That's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> over RF it would just be seen as voltage spikes at the rise and fall
> at the receiver. As such the square wave requires modulation of higher
> frequency carrier wave. Is this true?

Yes. Although theoretically you could transmit a square wave directly as radio waves, it is generally impracticable.

A wire can transfer static charge (voltage) and pass continuous current, so it can reproduce any 'square' wave down to DC. A radio wave consists of photons that each have a specific frequency. If you feed a square wave into an antenna it will output photons on all the component frequencies of the square wave. To do this efficiently the transmitting and receiving antennas would need multiple elements, each tuned to one of the harmonics of the square wave.

For example a 50 Hz symmetrical square wave would need antenna elements tuned to 50 Hz, 150 Hz, 250 Hz etc. The optimum length of a 1/4 wave whip antenna at 50 Hz is 1425 km. An antenna of practical length would only transmit some of the higher harmonics, and the received signal would be a series of spikes corresponding to the transitions.

A high frequency square wave could be sent directly with a practical antenna size, but would still need antennas tuned to that waveform, with multiple modes to handle the harmonics. To transmit several signals simultaneously in the same airspace, each one would have to be limited to a unique range of frequencies that didn't interfere with the other signals. This would be awkward and potentially a huge waste of bandwidth.

The solution to this problem is modulation. The frequencies in the [baseband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband) signal are moved up to a higher frequency band where they don't take up as much bandwidth proportionally, and a simple antenna with (proportionally) narrower bandwidth and higher efficiency can be used. The baseband signal and transmitting frequency are no longer related, so the antenna doesn't have be 'tuned' to the specific signal being transmitted.

> Is modulated FM signal and the carrier multiplied before transmission?

If you mean - is the FM signal generated at a lower frequency and then doubled or tripled etc. for transmission, the answer is it *may* be - depending on the the deviation required and type of modulator used. For good frequency stability a crystal controlled oscillator is often used, but its frequency can only be 'pulled' by a small amount with modulation. Greater deviation may be achieved by using a low frequency fundamental mode crystal, then multiplying the output to a higher frequency (which also multiplies the deviation by the same proportion). This may also be done if the transmitting frequency is too high for direct modulation.

Answer (score 2):

> Carrier Waves, modulation over RF vs on wire

RF stands for radio frequency. A signal which has a radio frequency carrier is RF, whether it is transmitted through a wire, a waveguide, or is "unguided", i.e. transmitted through "space" (including air). So, your counterposition of "RF" to "wire" is a bad dichotomy.

> From this, it seems I could generate a square wave for straight wire, but over RF it would just be seen as voltage spikes at the rise and fall at the receiver.

One can *modulate* a carrier with a square wave. Either using amplitude modulation (AM) or frequency modulation (FM).

> As such the square wave requires modulation of higher frequency carrier wave. Is this true?

Higher frequency than what?

> I note that FM carrier is a certain frequency

The frequency of an FM signal changes depending upon the amplitude of the modulating signal. Thus FM requires a range of frequencies to be available, rather than a single frequency.

Comment: I think some of my confusion is about accelerating charge producing EMR, and thinking for a signal the absolute value of the second derivative of antenna voltage must be positive.  That somehow this property differed from signaling just on wire. Above poster mentions this acceleration is not how a EM wave is generated on antenna. And EM can be generated in other ways